# configure error while checking dependency on libtiff

Tags: compilation, dependencies, libtiff

I have configured and make libtiff properly. Now I am trying to build another library which is dependent on the tiff library. I am getting the following error

```
checking for TIFF support ...
checking tiff.h usability... yes
checking tiff.h presence... yes
checking for tiff.h... yes
checking tiffio.h usability... yes
checking tiffio.h presence... yes
checking for tiffio.h... yes
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
checking for TIFFClientOpen in -ltiff... no
checking for TIFFIsByteSwapped in -ltiff... no
checking if TIFF package is complete... no -- some components failed test
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong. My configure statement is as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --with-zlib=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-tiff=yes --with-sysroot=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: check `config.log` output file. It is likely your newly built libtiff is not found

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed. I forgot to include another dependent library. libtiff was built with jbig support. I forgot to include jbig in LDFLAGS while configuring the new library which is dependent on libtiff.