# Undefined references in TIFF library

Tags: gcc, libtiff

I'm trying to compile [Panotools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/) for arm. I compiled all dependency libraries (TIFF, ZLIB, JPEG) but Panotools' `configure` is failing on libtiff:

> checking for TIFF support ...
>   configure: tiff home set to /usr/local
>   checking tiff.h usability... yes
>   checking tiff.h presence... yes
>   checking for tiff.h... yes
>   checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
>   checking if TIFF package is complete... no -- some components failed test
>   configure: error:
>   the tiff library must be installed on your system
>   but configure could not find it.

As you can see it can find `tiff.h`, and looking in `config.log` seems like it also finds the library but fails due to some undefined references. Here's some of the log:

```
configure:12446: checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff
configure:12471: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -IC:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff -IC:\PROGRA~2\GnuWin32\src\libjpeg\jpeg-6b -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -ltiff -lz -ljpeg -LC:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff\.libs -LC:\tiff-3.9.4\port\.libs -LC:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/src/libjpeg/jpeg-6b >&5
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_aux.o): In function `TIFFDefaultTransferFunction':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_aux.c:81: undefined reference to `pow'
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_aux.c:81: undefined reference to `floor'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_luv.o): In function `oog_encode':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_luv.c:776: undefined reference to `atan2'
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_luv.c:803: undefined reference to `atan2'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_luv.o): In function `LogL16toY':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_luv.c:657: undefined reference to `exp'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_luv.o): In function `L16toGry':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_luv.c:696: undefined reference to `sqrt'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_luv.o): In function `LogL16fromY':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_luv.c:672: undefined reference to `log'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_luv.o): In function `XYZtoRGB24':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_luv.c:725: undefined reference to `sqrt'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o):c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_pixarlog.c:901: more undefined references to `log' follow
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib\libtiff.a(tif_pixarlog.o): In function `PixarLogMakeTables':
c:\tiff-3.9.4\libtiff/tif_pixarlog.c:541: undefined reference to `exp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:12471: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| ...
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char TIFFOpen ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return TIFFOpen ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:12480: result: no
```

[Here](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-102501.html) someone's having the same problem but due to a different reason (libtiff can't be found at all). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341810/configure-error-while-checking-dependency-on-libtiff) it says that `jbig` is a dependency library for `libtiff` so I tried including it for the compiler (although [here](http://www.leptonica.org/vs2008doc/building-image-libraries.html) it isn't mentioned as a dependency library) and nothing changed.

Why am I getting those undefined references? Where are these symbols defined? Any library I need to add to the linker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these undefined references belong to the library `math` so just need to include it for the linker. Add this to the compilation command when running `configure`:

`LDFLAGS=-lm`